# sencha cmd packaging iphone 5

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am packaging sencha app into native iOS app. It is working fine but when I am running on iPhone 5, because of the launcher image (640X1136) is not in the .ipa file, the application is not available in the full screen. THe black stripes are displayed and application is visible in the iPhone 4 resolution.

**Note:** .ipa is generated via sencha cmd and packager.json is used to get the provisioning and certificates.

In the packager.json I can see the icons configuration but couldn't see the splash configuration. Can anyone point me out in the right direction, where I can configure the splash screen image setting for iPhone in the sencha touch app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap native build:

You need to set the image path in your phonegap config.xml file.  sample [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml)

```
 <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
```

For sencha touch Cmd native build try this:

In your packager.json add save your images in your resources/startup folder.   640x1096 is the one that will be used for iPhone5.

```
 'startupImage': 
    {
              '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
              '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
              '640x1096': 'resources/startup/640x1096.png',
              '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
              '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
              '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
              '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I am not using phonegap, I am using Sencha cmd for native packaging.

Comment: there should be a file in your directory resources/startup/640x920.png     don't change the name, just replace this startup image with a new 640x1136 size image.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check it and will inform then.

Comment: What about the naming convention? Default-568h@2x is not found, then it won't show up the startup screen for iphone 5 and won't show full resolution.